# R: Webscraping an xml page

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to webscrape a XML page into a dataframe to create a table as in
https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield

I tried:

```
library("XML")
library("methods")
xmldataframe <- xmlToDataFrame("http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%2011%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202017")
xmldataframe
```

But I could not get it to work properly.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want the table that contains "Date,1  Mo, 3 Mo,..."?

Comment: Yes, that is the table.

Comment: See the answer, I'm sure that it will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to use the package `rvest`, so try this

## To download:

```
if(!require("rvest")){install.packages("rvest");library("rvest")}
url <- "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield"

xml_page <- read_html(url)

detail <- xml_page %>%
  html_nodes(".text_view_data") %>% #node of the table
  html_text()
```

## Result

```
> detail
  [1] "11/01/17" "1.06"     "1.18"     "1.30"     "1.46"     "1.61"     "1.74"     "2.01"    
  [9] "2.22"     "2.37"     "2.63"     "2.85"     "11/02/17" "1.02"     "1.17"     "1.29"    
 [17] "1.46"     "1.61"     "1.73"     "2.00"     "2.21"     "2.35"     "2.61"     "2.83"    
 [25] "11/03/17" "1.02"     "1.18"     "1.31"     "1.49"     "1.63"     "1.74"     "1.99"    
 [33] "2.19"     "2.34"     "2.59"     "2.82"     "11/06/17" "1.03"     "1.19"     "1.30"    
 [41] "1.50"     "1.61"     "1.73"     "1.99"     "2.17"     "2.32"     "2.58"     "2.80"    
 [49] "11/07/17" "1.05"     "1.22"     "1.33"     "1.49"     "1.63"     "1.75"     "1.99"    
 [57] "2.17"     "2.32"     "2.56"     "2.77"     "11/08/17" "1.05"     "1.23"     "1.35"    
 [65] "1.53"     "1.65"     "1.77"     "2.01"     "2.19"     "2.32"     "2.57"     "2.79"    
 [73] "11/09/17" "1.07"     "1.24"     "1.36"     "1.53"     "1.63"     "1.75"     "2.01"    
 [81] "2.20"     "2.33"     "2.59"     "2.81"     "11/10/17" "1.06"     "1.23"     "1.37"    
 [89] "1.54"     "1.67"     "1.79"     "2.06"     "2.27"     "2.40"     "2.67"     "2.88"    
 [97] "11/13/17" "1.07"     "1.24"     "1.37"     "1.55"     "1.70"     "1.82"     "2.08"    
[105] "2.27"     "2.40"     "2.67"     "2.87"     "11/14/17" "1.06"     "1.26"     "1.40"    
[113] "1.55"     "1.68"     "1.81"     "2.06"     "2.26"     "2.38"     "2.64"     "2.84"
```

Then, you have to adapt it to the format you need

## Edit:

## To dataframe

This is clearly not a ellegant way but it works.

```
table_names<-c("Date","1 Mo","3 Mo",    "6 Mo", "1 Yr", "2 Yr", "3 Yr", "5 Yr", "7 Yr", "10 Yr",    "20 Yr",    "30 Yr")
ndates<-sum(grepl("/",detail))
df_detail<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = ndates,ncol = length(table_names)))
names(df_detail)<-table_names

pos1<-which(grepl("/",detail))
pos2<-which(grepl("/",detail))-1
pos2<-pos2[-1]
pos2<-c(pos2,length(detail))

for(i in 1:ndates){
  df_detail[i,]<-detail[pos1[i]:pos2[i]]

}
```

## Result

```
> df_detail
       Date 1 Mo 3 Mo 6 Mo 1 Yr 2 Yr 3 Yr 5 Yr 7 Yr 10 Yr 20 Yr 30 Yr
1  11/01/17 1.06 1.18 1.30 1.46 1.61 1.74 2.01 2.22  2.37  2.63  2.85
2  11/02/17 1.02 1.17 1.29 1.46 1.61 1.73 2.00 2.21  2.35  2.61  2.83
3  11/03/17 1.02 1.18 1.31 1.49 1.63 1.74 1.99 2.19  2.34  2.59  2.82
4  11/06/17 1.03 1.19 1.30 1.50 1.61 1.73 1.99 2.17  2.32  2.58  2.80
5  11/07/17 1.05 1.22 1.33 1.49 1.63 1.75 1.99 2.17  2.32  2.56  2.77
6  11/08/17 1.05 1.23 1.35 1.53 1.65 1.77 2.01 2.19  2.32  2.57  2.79
7  11/09/17 1.07 1.24 1.36 1.53 1.63 1.75 2.01 2.20  2.33  2.59  2.81
8  11/10/17 1.06 1.23 1.37 1.54 1.67 1.79 2.06 2.27  2.40  2.67  2.88
9  11/13/17 1.07 1.24 1.37 1.55 1.70 1.82 2.08 2.27  2.40  2.67  2.87
10 11/14/17 1.06 1.26 1.40 1.55 1.68 1.81 2.06 2.26  2.38  2.64  2.84
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. But it seems to be a character string. How can I convert it into a dataframe table?

Comment: These are two questions in one. But see the answer again. I'm sure this is not the best way to adapt it into data frame but it works.

Comment: That is really great. Thanks very much for all your help.